# Backup database connection in ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, connection-string, mirror

I have a problem. My school's databases are only accessible locally. So when I work from home or without an internet connection, I need to switch out the connectionString in my web.config to reflect a local database.

Is there a way to have two seperate connectionstrings, where one is used if the other is unavailable? Also, can I automatically mirror the first one to my local DB if it's available?

I should mention; this is a Web Forms project using .NET 4.0

Comment: Is this some sort of personal app that allows you to connect to the school DB for your own purpose or part of a business app?

Comment: There are two separate questions in one tread, please keep one only. Common use case "to maintain separate db connections" is to have One web.config with multiple configuration folders in your service hosting projects. Basically, your web.config will have this section to reference them : <connectionStrings configSource=".\Config\Dev\connectionStrings.config" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common use case "to maintain separate db connections" is to have 1 web.config with multiple configuration folders in your service hosting project.

Basically, your web.config should have connectionStrings section to reference each configuration environment (Dev/Local/QA/Prod):

`<connectionStrings configSource=".\Config\Dev\connectionStrings.config" />`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible to do directly, options could include:
1) Have a flag set either in config or elsewhere to signify the environment you are working in
2) Have a custom method for retrieving the connection string, this could then potentially catch a failed db connection and try again with the other string (you could also save the appropriate string in session for connections after the first one)